# MySQL database connections broke after DataGrip Upgrade (2021.3.x)

Tags: mysql, driver, amazon-aurora, datagrip

After upgrading DataGrip to version 2021.3.2, my existing db connections were broken.  I connect to various DBs (Oracle, MySql) via an SSH tunnel configured to connect through an AWS bastion host.

After the upgrade - DataGrip suggested that the MySql driver had to be updated to Amazon Aurora MySQL driver and it no longer worked to connect where it worked before the upgrade.

Switching between drivers I get two separate errors:

First Error using Amazon Aurora MySQL (suggested driver after update)

> [08000][-1] Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=53929)(type=master) : (conn=57522706) could not load system variables[08000][1220] (conn=57522706) Connection is closed.

and second error using original MySQL driver

> [08S01]
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate).

All of my connections worked immediately prior to the DataGrip upgrade - so seems that upgrade requires new drivers, which have a problem with the way I connect.

Answer (score 7):

After some looking - it seems that Aurora has an existing race condition - found my answer here: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-824?focusedCommentId=165412&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-165412

My solution was to change my usePipelineAuth to false (not set prior) in the **Advanced** tab of the Data Sources configuration:

[image: DataGrip Advanced Connections]

This fixed my connections and am back in business.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, In my case, I fix the issue just replacing/using `MariaDB` Driver.

[image]